# Logstash configuration for word extraction

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am new to Logstash manipulations and I have no idea how to do the below.
I have a sample data as below:

```
Column:Type
Incident Response P3
Incident Resolution L1.5  P2
...
```

**I want to extract the word 'Response' and 'Resolution' into a new column 'SLA type'**

Im looking for something very alike to the below SQL statement:

```
case when Type like '%Resolution%' then Resolution
when Type like '%Response%' then Response 
end as SLA_Type
```

How do i manipulate this in Logstash?

Below is my conf. I'm using an API input.

```
input {

http_poller {
    urls => {
    snowinc => {
    url => "https://service-now.com"
    user => "your_user"
    password => "yourpassword"
    headers => {Accept => "application/json"}
    }
}
request_timeout => 60
metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
codec => "json"
}
}
filter
   {
   json {source => "result" }
   split{ field => ["result"] }
date {
  match => ["[result][sys_created_on]","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
  target => "sys_created_on"
     }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["yourelastuicIP"]
    index => "incidentsnow"
    action=>update
    document_id => "%{[result][number]}"
    doc_as_upsert =>true
}
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The output for the API json url looks like the below:

```
{"result":[
{
"made_sla":"true",
"Type":"incident resolution p3",
"sys_updated_on":"2019-12-23 05:00:00",
"number":"INC0010275",
"category":"Network"} ,
{
"made_sla":"true",
"Type":"incident resolution l1.5 p4",
"sys_updated_on":"2019-12-24 07:00:00",
"number":"INC0010567",
"category":"DB"}]}
```

Comment: is that how data looks like? `Incident` always comes before `Response` or `Resolution`? if so `/^Incident \b([\w]+)\b/gm` should get you. Clarify my above question and add more of that data. I can write a `conf` file to show you the `filter`

Comment: @JBone, My output is not always necessarily in the same order, which is why I want to pick out the words only. I've attached my conf file and a sample data set from my  API URL with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `filter` block in your pipeline to add a new field if a word is present in another field.

```
if "response" in [Type] {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "SLA_Type" => "Response" }
    }
}
if "resolution" in [Type] {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "SLA_Type" => "Resolution" }
    }
}
```

If the word *response* is present in the field `Type` a new field named `SLA_Type` with the value `Response` will be added to your document, the same in will happen with `resolution`.